# Dish soap reaction on braided stainless steel hose

Tags: acid-base

Just wondering if leaking dish soap can have a reaction on a braided stainless steel hose used for hot water intake of dishwasher over time (several months)? The hose which was new at the time perforated without explanation and caused a flood.
Thanks.

Comment: Highly unlikely in my opinion (as a chemist and dishwasher owner). If the water coming in was/is hard, there might have been some buildup on the intake screen (if there is/was one), but we'd need to know your water chemistry and more about the plumbing. Over-tightening the hose and/or having a bad gasket (usually old, thus easily cracked) can also be the cause. Dish soap would be way down the list.